# OpenCV Library for Android in Eclipse Error

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

After adding the OpenCV library to my workspace and designating it as a library project, I have one error that is troubling me. On the line:

```
mEngineService = OpenCVEngineInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
```

I get the following error:

```
Stub cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Clearly, looking at the file, *org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface* there is no field named Stub. So, what is a Stub, where can I find one? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `aidl` tool in the android sdk to convert the `OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl` file into `OpenCVEngineInterface.java`.